# geofield map theme markers

Tags: views, google-maps, location

I wonder if (and how) it is possible to have dynamic markers on a geofield map created by views. I'd like to have different colors of markers depending on a field value, and also a count of matches from a proximity filter direktly printed into the markers (not the popup). I'm using the google map layer and cannot find an option to even have (e.g.) green instead of the default red markers. Google search on this topic didn't wield any solutions.

I'm using the following modules: address field, geofield, geophp & geofield maps for map display.

Has anyone done this already? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean e.g. something like this http://ithaka.im/nl/route

Comment: @Justme more like so: http://www.leerstandsmelder.de/

Comment: I see, yes it is possible with openlayers 2.x. I did not got it working with openlayers 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

An instruction how to do this can be found on:
http://purewebmedia.biz/article/2014/08/01/create-multi-layer-map-drupal-7-openlayers-2x